# Converting Infix strings to Postfix strings with support for mulidigit numbers in Java

Tags: java

I was recently given an assignment in one of my classes that asked us to create a calculator that takes an Infix expression, turns it into a postfix expression, and then evaluates.

The problem stems from implementing multidigit numbers.
I thought of using spaces to denote multidigit numbers but I am almost positive that method wouldn't help for converting Infix to Postfix as that would only help the Postfix evaluation method see what is a multidigit number and what isn't.

I just need help figuring out how to do the conversion from infix to postfix.

Comment: how is the input? Is it a + b or a+b?

Comment: I probably should have specified that it's a+b

Comment: Search the string for the operator index. Grab the operator. Then split the string on the operator. You will end up with three parts. The first number, the operator, and the second number.

Comment: Would that work for expressions like 10+10?

Comment: The process is the same for all a+b. Single and multi-digits

Comment: Once you have the 3 parts in an array or list, you can rearrange them how you like.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I'll try that

Comment: Start off with just an addition string and once you figure that out you can do the logic for the other operations.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a scanning issue. It doesn't have anything specific to do with infix-postfix conversion. Scan a character at a time When you encounter a digit, include every following digit in the scan for that token. Stop when the next thing isn't a digit. It will then be either an operator, or, for completeness, white space. If it's whitespace, ignore it (but after terminating the digit string), otherwise return it to the parser.

You don't need spaces, but if you have them it will help scanning, and the user, not the evaluation method. The evaluation method already knows what the numbers are, as the scanner tells it.

Comment: What happens if the number is a float?

Comment: @SedrickJefferson I assume you mean 'real number'. To implement those, if you stop at a decimal point you keep scanning if there are following digits, but there's nothing about real numbers in the question.

Comment: In my approach if you split on the operator you will have the two number you need.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson I don't see anything in your answer that constitutes an 'approach'. Just a list of methods with comments. This answer shows how compilers do it. In compilers there is a strong emphasis on processing every character exactly once, for efficiency reasons. Using the methods you mention you would be processing each character several times, not to mention creating a lot more strings.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson Hard to see why you posted anything if you 'didn't want to do this problem'.

Comment: I didn't want to give the answer. The kid is learning. It's best to send them in the right direction and let them do most of the thinking.